# The value is displaying two times in drop down after adding the data using pop-up window in MVC4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i like to explain my issue with perfect example. I have two drop downs in my view one is **CustomerName** and another one is **ContactPerson** if i select the **CustomerName** the customer name related **ContactPerson** will load  automatically in contact person drop down. its like cascading drop down.

Suppose if i select the **CustomerName** and select the **ContactPerson** and the contact person name is not in the list means i have to add that. so i kept one add button near to contact person. if the contact person name is not in the list means i click that add button it open the partial view as popup window(i created one partial view and call that view in pop-up window).

[Partial View Popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHOXI.jpg)

Now i enter all the details and click the create button. it will save the value in db and i close the pop-up window.Now here only i got issue. That is after closing the popup window and if i select the contact person i shows the value two times in drop down but it save in db one time correctly. 
[value showing Two times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKci0.jpg)

In the above image you people can see the value is displaying two times after adding the value using popup window.This is the issue. please any one help me to clear this issue.

**My View Model**

```
   public class VisitorsViewModel
   {
    public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ContactID { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }  
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string AlternateEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

I created the properties for both partial view(child view) and main view(parent view) in  same View Model.

**My controller code to save data which is entered in pop-up window.**

```
 public ActionResult ContactPersonPartialView()
   {
    ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "DisplayName");   
    return View("ContactPersonPartialView");
   }
    [HttpPost]

 public JsonResult ContactPersonCreate(VisitorsViewModel VVviewmodel)
   {
     ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "DisplayName", VVviewmodel.CustomerID);
        var ContactIDObj = Guid.NewGuid();
        var CustomerContactIDObj = Guid.NewGuid();

        var CustomerContactObj = new CustomerContact()
        {
            CustomerContactID = CustomerContactIDObj,
            CustomerID = VVviewmodel.CustomerID,
            ContactReference = VVviewmodel.ContactPerson,
            ContactID = ContactIDObj,
            IsActive = true,
            IsDeleted = false,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            EditedDate = DateTime.Now,
            LastActiveOn = DateTime.Now,
            RowID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            CreatedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            EditedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            OfflineMode = false,
            OfflineID = Guid.NewGuid()
        };
        var ContactObj = new Contact()
        {
            ContactID = ContactIDObj,
            DisplayName = VVviewmodel.CustomerID.ToString(),
            PrintName = VVviewmodel.CustomerID.ToString(),
            Phone1 = VVviewmodel.PhoneNo,
            Mobile1 = VVviewmodel.MobileNo,
            Email1 = VVviewmodel.Email,
            Email2 = VVviewmodel.AlternateEmail

        };

        db.Contacts.Add(ContactObj);
        db.CustomerContacts.Add(CustomerContactObj);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ModelState.Clear();
       return Json(CustomerContactIDObj);
       }
```

**My Parent View Code**

```
 @Html.Label("Employee Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })

 @Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })

 @Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "CustomerContactID" })
            <button id="AddContactPerson">Add </button>
             <div id="AddNewContactPerson"></div>
```

**My Main View J query code to open popup window**

```
   $(function () {
     $('#AddNewContactPerson').dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       width: 400,
       height:500,
       resizable: false,
       title: 'Add New',
       modal: true,
       open: function(event, ui) {
       $(this).load("@Url.Action("ContactPersonPartialView", "VisitorsForm")");
       },
       buttons: {
       "Close": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        }
        }
    });

        $("#AddContactPerson").click(function () {
        $("#AddNewContactPerson").dialog("open");
       });
       });
```

**My Partial View code**

```
        @Html.Label("Customer Name")
        @Html.DropDownList("CustomerID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control " ,id="Customer"})

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactPerson)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactPerson, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactPerson) 

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text",id="EmailID"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)


  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.4-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function SaveContact() {
    debugger;
    var CustomerID = $("#Customer").val();
    var ContactPerson = $("#ContactPerson").val();
    var Email = $("#EmailID").val();
    var AlternateEmail = $("#AlternateEmail").val();
    var PhoneNo = $("#PhoneNo").val();
    var MobileNo = $("#MobileNumber").val();
    alert(CustomerID);
    alert(Email);
    alert(MobileNo);

    var CustomerContact = {
        "ContactPerson":  '' +ContactPerson+'', "Email": '' +Email+ '',
        "AlternateEmail": '' +AlternateEmail+ '', "PhoneNo": '' +PhoneNo+ '',
        "MobileNo": ''+ MobileNo+ '', "CustomerID": ''+CustomerID+''
        };
   $.post("/VisitorsForm/ContactPersonCreate", CustomerContact, function (data) {
   $('#CustomerContactID').append($('<option><option>').val(data).text(ContactPerson));

        alert("sucess");
   });
   }
```

I hope i try my level best to tell my issue with you peoples please any one give me solution to solve this problem. I know that my issue is too long but any one understand my issue and give me solution.

Advance Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$('#CustomerContactID').append($('<option>option>').val(data).text(ContactPerson));
```

with

```
var option = new Option(ContactPerson, data);
$('#CustomerContactID').append($(option));
```

Answer (score 0):

On your partial view you are manually appending the ContactPerson after an http POST.

This causes the main view to reload the contact person list before the new contact is added.

In short,

Data Reloaded (Contains new contact option) + Append new option = Double Entry

Try removing

```
$('#CustomerContactID').append($('<option><option>').val(data).text(ContactPerson));
```

on on your partial view code.

Comment: Ephraim if i remove that line the value is not displaying in the drop down once i refresh the whole page and  again i have to select the customer name  the contact person is there. i don't want this. if i add once it want to show the value one time in contact person dropdown.

Comment: So the option appears but after a refresh it's gone right? Can you show us how you populate the dropdownlistfor the customercontactid? Maybe the HttpGet ActionResult for the main view?

Comment: No Ephraim once i add the value using pop-up window and close the pop-up window and select the dropdown the value is not there once i refresh the whole parent view and again select the customer name the contact person name which i recently added using pop-up window is load. wait i will show the output image after removing that line .

Comment: Ephraim now i open my view and enter the employee name, Date, select the customer name and select the contatc person name and it is not list so i  added the value by click the add button.[Added contact person][2][2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4HuLZ.jp now i Select anand for WafeSoftware Customer now i close the pop-up window and selec the customer name the recently added customer name is not in the list which i recently added which is in below image[contactperson  in DD][1] [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FPoxM.jpg. so i have to refresh the whole page again.This is the OP of removing that line.

Comment: @Susan FYI 1st image link is broken. Anyway, if you don't remove the that line the new contact person appears twice on the list options but if it is removed then no new contact person is added on the list options. Correct? I see you added an alert. Is there any indication that the alert appears twice when you save the new contact person?